# HighCharts Boost Module Arearange

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, time-series, react-highcharts

When I plot time series data as area range with boost module enabled, if some points have the same value for min and max, the chart renders them as breaks in the range graph. Whereas if boost is disabled, it shows them is dips.

[image: Boost module enabled and the breakage in the series is from min and max points being equal]

[image: Boost module disabled, graph is continuous]

[Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/highcharts-boost-forked-97ksn4?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A61%2C25&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvhtxou00063b6ablhbvsoh%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvhtxou00023b6arviqrs9e%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvhtxou00033b6alpesyepl%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvhtxou00053b6az2ozg96o%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpvhtxou00023b6arviqrs9e%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvhtxot00013b6akxvo16uy%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A61%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A25%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A61%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A25%257D%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvhtxou00023b6arviqrs9e%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpvhtxot00013b6akxvo16uy%2522%257D%252C%2522clpvhtxou00053b6az2ozg96o%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvhtxou00043b6a475mhsjp%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvhtxou00053b6az2ozg96o%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpvhtxou00043b6a475mhsjp%2522%257D%252C%2522clpvhtxou00033b6alpesyepl%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpvhtxou00033b6alpesyepl%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: I would suggest reporting this bug on the official GitHub library repository and possibly attaching a ticket here. You can do it using this link: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose